# Optimizing search for values in columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am fairly new to SQL Server and i am having this issue with this very big table that was implemented in a rather awkward way. Here is summary picture of what the design looks like

**Table A**

```
itemID uniqueidentifier PK
name   vchar(32)
datecreated datetime
dateprocessed datetime
datereviewed datetime
approvalstatus int
workflowstatus int
```

**Table B**

```
fieldID uniqueidentifier PK
itemID  uniqueidentifier FK(referencing table A's itemID)
name    vchar(32)
value   vchar(32)
```

In table A we have record of transactions with some of the fields being populated to Table B. Like say `AccountNumber` for a transactions in table A is populated to table B with name = accountnumber and value = '[actual account number]' with the required itemID. Now table B is extremely large so that querying for account number for a specific transaction using a  view is taking forever.

Mind you all this name columns were previously in table A but due to always changing business needs to add more columns led the team to create the structure this way so that adding new fields would not require adding new columns to table A.

What is the best way to optimize this table.

Comment: Add more details please, it's quite dificult to help with this amount of information - especially for optimizing. E.g. I don't see the fields "accountnumber" and "transaction" or their values anywere and I don't get why should you look up "actual account number" in table B - from the info you published it seems it's a simple 'insert' command...

Comment: @mark table A has some of the data for a transaction why the remaining fields are inserted into Table B, table b is now very large and takes forever to search based on other fields that have been inserted into table B. Its like breaking the table into 2 with name value for some of fields inserted into table B

Comment: I see. In this case: it's not possible to do "high quality optimizations" by keeping this model. What you need to do is either redesigning the DB (which would be the only good solution) or for a quick&dirty "coming out" :) introduce a new key field in tableB which is an ID defined in a EAV table, telling the [name] field's "type". So EAV is something like "AccountNumber=1, Transaction=2, etc". This way you can filter out loads of records before you start searching in TableB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your colleagues created are an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) store. I'll leave aside whether those are evil things or not.

The short answer is: you cannot optimize your queries.

The longer answer is: you might be able to toss in an (indexed) type field in the AV your table B, to make things slightly more efficient.

Depending on what you store in it, a slightly related option might be to maintain extra typed fields therein using triggers, and indexing the latter as well. For instance, a trigger could maintain an `int` field that holds the integer value of fields marked as having a type of `int`.

That said, don't count on a great performance boost with those solutions, since you'll still be doing lots of needless joins. And keep in mind that both of these tricks add overhead (extra disk space + time related to index maintenance).

The correct answer is: an EAV store should only ever get used to store *meta* information.

By meta, I mean stuff that you'll seldom use a where clause on, let alone a very selective one.

In other words, identify the key fields that are frequently queried against, whether for where clauses, join clauses, order by clauses, etc. Shift them back into table A, and index them properly.

While you're at it, consider moving stuff that is present in most/all rows from table A as well: each field that you move will save you space due to no longer needing that `name` field in table B, and you'll get appropriately typed data as a bonus.