# Query to arrange the order of execution of Where Clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a database where some parts are indexed why some parts are not properly indexed due to business requirements using Entity Attribute Value(See here : [Optimizing search for values in columns in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16208900/optimizing-search-for-values-in-columns-in-sql-server))

Now what I am trying to do is to write a query to fetch the result from the properly indexed table first before querying the unindexable table i.e. I have datecreated on table A(properly indexed table), I want to return the data between a date range before searching specific value on Table B(no index).

```
select *
from TableA a
join TableB b on a.ItemID = b.ItemID
where a.DateCreated between '2013-05-01' and '2013-05-31'
and b.Value in   ('2062572376','2062577601','2062577766','2062577900')
```

What is the best way to achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: It's easier if you don't use `SELECT *` so you can use a covering index. It's going to be hard to optimise it otherwise. Also add table structures please

Comment: the index that I have only uses 3 of my columns and the tables has several columns that I need returned that are not in my index

Comment: That doesn't help. Add the tables and remove the SELECT *

Comment: The optimizer should work out the most efficient way to execute the query. That's why there's nothing built into the SQL language to let you specify this - the whole point is you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. There are hints that can be applied in T-SQL, but if you find yourself using them, it's usually a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever What kind of hints would work for this scenario